# Django CMS placeholders

Tags: django-cms

Im currently working on a Django CMS project and see different placeholders on the pages - TOP, LEFT, CENTER,RIGHT, BOTTOM, HIDDEN.

I know how the plugins work but not sure how to have these multiple placeholders on the page. Anyone could direct me in the right direction would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.. are you trying to create a page with other placeholders?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of placeholders in django-cms. Standard placeholders, and static placeholders.

The standard placeholders can be added to templates and will be made available on all standard CMS pages using those templates. These placeholders can hold different plugins for each page they're used on.

Standard placeholders are quite simple, and added to templates with `{% placeholder "section_line-events" %}`.

Static placeholders provide a single placeholder for the whole site, identified by a given name. For example, your footer would likely be a static placeholder so that it's the same on all pages.

Also, if you've got applications hooked in to CMS, the templates in those apps needs to use static placeholders instead of standard placeholders if you need to allow the use of plugins within your apps.

For example, if you've got an application which you add some default content to, but want to make editable by your user/client you could add a static placeholder;

```
{% static_placeholder 'my_app_placeholder' site or %}
    Default text for this placeholder.
{% endstatic_placeholder %}
```